# Leetcode 1255-recursion and backtracking

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, clone, backtracking

I dont quite understand why have we used .clone() method when we have a second for loop to restore the letterCount.And when i'm runnig this code without `.clone()` method its giving me the wrong answer? So what exactly is the need

```
public int solution(String[] words, int[] letterCount, int[] score, int ind) {
    if (ind == words.length)
        return 0;

    int sno = solution(words, letterCount.clone(), score, ind + 1); // Skip word

    String word = words[ind];
    int sword = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        int letterIndex = ch - 'a';
        if (letterCount[letterIndex] == 0) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
        letterCount[letterIndex]--;
        sword += score[letterIndex];
    }

    int syes = 0;
    if (flag) 
        syes = sword + solution(words, letterCount, score, ind + 1); // Use word

    // Restore letterCount 
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        letterCount[ch - 'a']++;
    }
    return Math.max(sno, syes);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backtracking doesn't work, as you break when the count of a letter drops to 0, but the loop that restores the counts unconditionally adds all the letters back.

If you remove the `break`, then your code will work correctly without cloning.

```java
for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
    int letterIndex = ch - 'a';
    if (letterCount[letterIndex] == 0)
        flag = false;
    letterCount[letterIndex]--;
    sword += score[letterIndex];
}
```